# Background processing in Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, background, glassfish

There are many questions and answers about this: how to run long-running "standalone" processes in the context/confines of a J2EE server.

In my case I am asking specifically about Glassfish:

- Self-contained process (Java, of course) which does not expect any HTTP requests ever but fetches data from some 3rd party service A and transfers it to some 3rd party service B.
- It should start at the start of the J2EE server, and end on shutdown (the server instance is dedicated to this process).
- Any specialties of this server can and should be used, if it offers anything beyond the usual J2EE fare of `Timer` started in a `ServletContext`.

Does Glassfish offer anything special for this? Or is using a `Timer` still the best solution? Are there problems if said timer never ends (except on server shutdown), or will the J2EE server auto-terminate it after a while?

The question of whether this is the correct architecture is out-of-scope here; the customer enforces that this process must run within a Glassfish.

Comment: Have You looked into the batch processing api in recent versions of Java EE?

Comment: Looks interesting, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html . I'll see if I get something to work with that. I don't need all the `ItemReader` etc. stuff, I'll need to see how I can get a "small version" for my specific use case...